# CSS class assigned to a taxonomy term

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-taxonomy

Imagine a blog with 4 different taxonomy terms.
I want to display "all blog items," but every blog item with the term "design" will have a different look. So what I'd want is to have a CSS class for rows within a node. Am I saying that right?

I probably did this in a gross, really hacky way, but here it is:

```
if (isset($fields["tid"]->content)) {
  unset($classes);
  unset($class);
  unset($classarray);

  $classarray = explode(",", $fields["tid"]->content);
  echo '<div class="';

  foreach ($classarray as $class) {
    $class = str_replace('<span class="field-content">', "", $class);
    $class = str_replace("</span>", "", $class);
    $class = str_replace(" ", "", $class);
    echo strtolower($class) . " ";
    unset($class);
  }

  echo '">';
}
else {
    echo "<div>";
}
```

Then I had a `</div>` tag at the end of the file.

This does require you to add the taxonomy details as content when you define your content type, and hide it with some CSS.

Well, I hope this might help someone, even though it's bad form.

Comment: Thanks for updating us with your progress.  It does look here like you may be doing more work than you need to be doing.  It might be worth looking into, to see if there is an element $fields['tid']->raw - this might save you some of the parsing / tag removal you're doing here.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, James, but it sends out an ID instead of the actual words. There's probably a way to do it by setting the field to "hidden" inside the "content type" configuration, but I haven't been able to track the outcome with said "hidden" setting. Bugger.

Comment: Kiorrik, this depends on what you select for taxonomy in views fields.  If I recall correctly, there's taxonomy term and taxonomy id - at any rate, one provides the tid (term id) & the other the actual term (words).  You may also want to dump the whole relevant $fields element to find it.  This is how drupal theming & coding goes, you always have so many **** elements of these huge arrays to sift through.

Comment: Cheers once more for the answers :) I'm still just getting started with Drupal but having lots of fun - apart from the parts where you spend days searching haystacks for needles.

Comment: Thank you for your responses, Kiorrik, it's always more fun providing answers when you get a bit of input back.  Success to you & your site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display "all blog items," you'll need to create a view.

You can then create a custom template for that view, altering it to insert the taxonomy term as a class name into the HTML.

Comment: Any idea what template this should be (dislpay output, style output, row style output), what variable(s) to add, etc? Like I said, my knowledge of Drupal is minimal... So, I'm very sorry but I'm going to need a bit more details :(

Comment: It looks like you got some of it above.  I wish I could comment more, but I always have to trawl through these files and variables myself whenever it comes to theming a view.  The drupal for firebug module helps this process alot, it must be said - it can save you a lot of time.  Good luck with your theming & code!

Comment: Thanks a lot, will definitely try that one!